# Python smtplib.SMTP connection failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to send an email and this code works on another box but it will not work on this one.  I am assuming that it is firewall related but I do not know how to resolve it.

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=15)
    print("defined server")
    server.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    print("Connected")
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    print("starttls")
    server.login(username, password)
    print("login")
    server.sendmail(username, vtext, message)
    print("sendmail")
    server.quit()
```

I opened port 587 and *telnet smtp.gmail.com 587* works.

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\pcunningham\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 398, in getreply
> line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
> File "C:\Users\pcunningham\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
> return self._sock.recv_into(b)
> socket.timeout: timed out
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\pcunningham\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "c:\Users\pcunningham\Desktop\Email\Form.py", line 78, in send_text
> server.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
> File "C:\Users\pcunningham\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 343, in connect
> (code, msg) = self.getreply()
> File "C:\Users\pcunningham\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 401, in getreply
> raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed: "
> smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: timed out

Comment: Sounds like a firewall is bocking the connection. Can you use a mail client to send through gmail on that machine?